# how to implement arithmetic operation inside if/else condition in velocity template

Tags: java, velocity

I have a condition where,

```
if(|$Id|>=1000) $Id/100 #end|
```

if condition passes I need to arithmetic operation of the value to be displayed.
But currently I get `$Id/100` like a string.
How do i achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

to execute arithmetic operation in velocity add an assignment line to a variable and then display the value

```
#set ($Id = $Id / 100)

$Id
```

Or you can use [MathTool division](https://velocity.apache.org/tools/1.4/generic/MathTool.html#div()):

```
$math.div($Id, 100)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [MathTool](https://velocity.apache.org/tools/1.4/generic/MathTool.html) external library, you can do the needed arithmetic operations easily. For how it works, please check the below steps:

1. Import `velocity-tools` library into your project.
2. Add a new instance of `MathTool` into your `VelocityContext`.

   Example `params.put("math", new MathTool());`
3. Then you can start using this lib inside your velocity template, example:

```
    #if ($id >= 1000)
        #set ($id = $math.div($id, 100))
        $id
    #end
```

Maybe it's a late answer, but details here could help others that are still stuck.